# Check string and htmlentities everything within the pre

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am in the middle of trying to code a comment form.

I was thinking of using strstr to find if `<pre>` exists and if it does turn everything within it into html safe using htmlentities.

But I am coming into a problem of actually converting everything within the pre.

My code becomes true but how to replace.

I was looking at preg_replace but my regex is really poor at best :)

Example:

```
$string = 'This is a form with <pre>Everything in this needs to be htmlentities() </pre> and everything outside needs to be normal.';
```

Comment: can you illustrate with some of your code what your doing, hard to understand with the current form of the question.

Comment: @DevZer0 Basically the form is just a basic form which I call using $_Post['content'] and then use strstr to find if the < pre > exists. I am wanting to turn only the text within the < pre > to be made to use htmlentities and everything else be normal

Comment: use a dom parser because if there is tags inside it just makes awful regex. my advise to you use a dom parser extract the pre from the input escape it as you wish and then put it back

Comment: @DevZer0 updated, sorry it never showed the pre or anything :)

Comment: Why not turn everything around `<pre>` into HTML safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I got your question right, then this should work:

```
$string_new = preg_replace_callback(
    '#<pre>([\\s\\S]+?)</pre>#',
    create_function(
        '$input',
        'return "<pre>".htmlentities($input[1])."</pre>";'
    ),
    $string
);
```

Comment: this is nearly 100% :) but your code removes the pre tags for some reason

Comment: This works, Regex is really cool, just wish I could understand it :( cant find any good threads to explain how it works

Comment: There is an issue with this, if you have more than 1 < pre >< /pre> in one comment it only takes the first < pre > and the last < /pre> and then everything in between has htmlentities.

Comment: My bad, regex is greedy by default, should be working now. Also: http://www.bitcetera.com/en/techblog/2008/04/01/regex-in-a-nutshell/ . Don't know if the tutorial is good, but the cheat sheet is pretty nice.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ no because the answer did not work, it worked if only 1 instance of < pre> was given, but if there was more than 1 it just wrapped all content in Pre tags - Just noticed the above, will try it and then mark as answered :)

Comment: Did the trick :) @bone-idle thanks for the link, reading and learning, thank you :)